# Route.php can't find controller class I created

Tags: php, silex

I'm trying to build a silex application. My file structure is:

```
ROOT/
    /App/
        /Controller/{IndexController.php}
        /Config/{dev.php,prod.php,route.php}
    /vendor
    /web/{index.php, index_dev.php}
```

When I'm trying to see `http://localhost/web/` I get error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Controller\IndexController' not found in ../App/config/route.php on line 2

Here are the relevant files:

**index_dev.php**

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

require __DIR__.'/../App/config/dev.php';
$app = require __DIR__.'/../App/app.php';

$app->run();

?>
```

**app.php**

```
<?php

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app = new Application();

require __DIR__.'/config/route.php';
return $app;

?>
```

**route.php**

```
<?php

$app->mount('/', new App\Controller\IndexController());

?>
```

**IndexController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Silex\ControllerCollection;

class IndexController implements ControllerProviderInterface {

  public function index(Application $app) {
    return phpinfo();
  }

  public function connect(Application $app) {
    $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

    $app->get('/', 'App\Controller\IndexController::index');

    return $controllers;
  }

}

?>
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.0.*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: Have you installed silex with `composer`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing autoloder options in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": { "psr-0": { "App": "./" } }
```

Comment: In which place should I add this?

Comment: anywhere in main object, ie after minimum stability line.