# using Silex framework for the routing

Tags: php, silex

Hello everyone I would like to use the MicroFramework Silex to create the routing part of my website. The problem that I walk into is that I can't make it work since I don't really understand the documentation.

I have implemented the required files in my file tree and added some code into the index.php

this code is as follows:

```
$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app->post('/web/{slug}', __DIR__.'/Controller/PostsController::showPost()');

$app->run();
```

I have also created a directory called Controller with the PostsController class in it. but now I don't know how to continue Can someone give me a simple example of how to create a dynamic routing that works with my Navigation class?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing filepath and class name / callback function. Second argument passed to `post/get/match` methods must be something that can be resolved to callable, so it can be lambda function, array of object/class and method name or string with function / class::method, ie.:

```
//Lambda
$app->get('/web/{slug}', function(){
        return \MyNamespace\Controler\PostControler::showPost();
    }
);    

//Static call
$app->get('/web/{slug}', array('\\MyNamespace\\Controler\\PostControler','showPost'));

//Object call
$myCtrl = new \MyNamespace\Controler\PostControler();
$app->get('/web/{slug}', array($myCtrl,'showPost'));

//Function
function showPost(){
    return \MyNamespace\Controler\PostControler\showPost();
}
$app->get('/web/{slug}', 'showPost');

//Both static and not methods
$app->get('/web/{slug}', '\\MyNamespace\\Controler\\PostControler::showPost');
```

When creating your own namespaces, [remember to add them to autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200941/route-php-cant-fide-controller-class-i-created)

Comment: This is mostly correct, but the controller is not a callable. It's a value that can be resolved to a callable by the controller resolver. This means that the final example works for both static and non-static methods. The controller resolver detects both cases and creates the instance for non-static methods. Which is what I would generally suggest either way.